# When i add the code to set the path and want to retrieve the file(which is choose 2 inside my program), it will show segmentation fault(core dump)

Tags: c, tcp

This was my uni project, i am still new to this TCP/IP program.
Anyone can help me please.
Everything is ok ,when i add the code at the choose 2 and set the path .

```
/*inet.h*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define SERV_TCP_PORT 25000
#define SERV_UDP_PORT 35001
#define CLI_UDP_PORT 35002
```

Below is my server.c

```
/*server.c*/
 #include "inet.h"
 #define BUFSIZE 1024

int main(){
int sockfd,new_sockfd,clilen;
char buffer[BUFSIZE+1];
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr,cli_addr;
int bytereceive = 0;

if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0){
perror("Server : socker() error\n");
exit(1);}
printf("\nBank Account Management\n");

bzero( (char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr("192.168.204.129");
//serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port=htons(SERV_TCP_PORT);

if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0){
perror("Server :bind() error\n");
exit(1);}
printf("\nWaiting for connection...[bind]\n");

    /* Get the user name */ 
    char *buf; 
    buf=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char)); 
    buf=getlogin(); 

    /* set the 'server' path */ 
    char str[30]; 
    strcpy(str, "/home/"); 
    strcat(str, buf); 
    strcat(str, "/server/"); 

    /* Check the path exist or not, if not, create one */ 
    struct stat s; 
    if(stat(str, &s) == -1){ 
    mkdir(str, 0700); }

listen(sockfd,5);
    int p[2];
    if(pipe(p) == -1)
    {
        perror("Fail to create pipe");
        exit(1);
    } 

for(;;){

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    new_sockfd=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,&clilen);
    char *clientaddress = inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr);
    char *individual_address; 
    write(p[1], &clientaddress, sizeof(clientaddress));



if(fork() == 0){
      close(sockfd);
      strcpy(buffer,"** Hello, welcome to the server. ** \n\nPress 1 to register !!!\nPress 2 to to download the transaction history file!!!\nPress 3 to check the balance!!!\nPress /q to logout!!!");





      send(new_sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);

if(new_sockfd>0)
      read(p[0],&individual_address,sizeof(individual_address));
      printf("\nClient %s connected now.\n", individual_address);


do{
    recv(new_sockfd,buffer,BUFSIZE,0);

    if(!strcmp(buffer,"1"))
    {



        int fd;

    fd=open("abc.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT ,0755);




    bzero(buffer,sizeof(buffer));

    recv(new_sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);

    lseek(fd,9,SEEK_SET);

    write(fd,buffer,8);

    bzero(buffer,sizeof(buffer));

    recv(new_sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);

    lseek(fd,(off_t)-1,SEEK_END);

    write(fd,buffer,3);


    close(fd);


    }

if(!strcmp(buffer, "2"))
{       
        printf("Type history.txt to send the file");        
        bzero( buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        gets(buffer);
        send(sockfd,buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);

        char filename[30];
    strcpy(filename, "/home/"); 
    strcat(filename, buf); 
    strcat(filename, "/server/");

    strcat(filename, buffer);

    FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(filename, "r"); 

    bzero( buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    int nread = fread(buffer,1,256,fp);
    send(sockfd, buffer, nread, 0); 







}


}while (strcmp(buffer,"/q"));
    printf("\nClient %s disconnected now.\n", individual_address);
    exit(0);
exit(0);
}
close(new_sockfd);
}
close(sockfd);

}
```

Below is my client.c

```
 /* client.c */
 #include "inet.h"
 #define BUFSIZE 1024

int main(){
int sockfd,new_sockfd;
char buffer[BUFSIZE+1];

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
static struct sigaction act;

/*it will ignore when the user type CTRL C */
void catchin(int);
act.sa_handler = catchin;
sigfillset(&(act.sa_mask));
sigaction(SIGINT, &act, (void *) 0);

if(argc <=1){
printf("HOw to use : %s remoteIPaddress [example:./client 127.0.0.1]\n",argv[0]);exit(1);}

bzero((char *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERV_TCP_PORT);
inet_pton(AF_INET,argv[1],&serv_addr.sin_addr);

if((sockfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0))<0){
perror("Client:socker() error\n");
exit(1);}

if(connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0){
perror("Client :connect() error\n");
exit(1);}

    /* Get the user name */ 
    char *buf; 
    buf=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char)); 
    buf=getlogin(); 

    /* set the 'client' path */ 
    char str[30]; 
    strcpy(str, "/home/"); 
    strcat(str, buf); 
    strcat(str, "/client"); 

    /* Check the path exist or not, if not, create one */ 
    struct stat s; 
    if(stat(str, &s) == -1){ 
    mkdir(str, 0700); }

bzero( buffer, sizeof(buffer));
recv(sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);
printf("\n%s\n", buffer); 

do{

bzero( buffer, sizeof(buffer));
gets(buffer);
send(sockfd,buffer,BUFSIZE,0);

if(!strcmp(buffer, "1"))
{

bzero(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
printf("\nPlease enter the username :\n");
gets(buffer);
send(sockfd,buffer,BUFSIZE,0);

bzero(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
printf("\nPlease enter the password :\n");
gets(buffer);
send(sockfd,buffer,BUFSIZE,0);

bzero( buffer, sizeof(buffer));
printf("Successfully register.\n");
printf("\nPress 1 to register\n");
printf("Press 2 to download the transaction history file\n");
printf("Press 3 to check the balance\n");
printf("Press /q to logout\n");
gets(buffer);
send(sockfd,buffer,BUFSIZE,0);

}

else if(!strcmp(buffer, "2"))
{   

        bzero( buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        recv(new_sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);

        char filename[30];
        strcpy(filename, "/home/"); 
        strcat(filename, buf); 
        strcat(filename, "/client/");
        strcat(filename, buffer);


        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(filename, "w+"); 
        bzero( buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        bytereceive = recv(new_sockfd, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);
        fwrite(buffer,1,bytereceive,fp);
        fclose(fp);





    printf("\nSuccessfully reveice the transaction history file.\n");
    printf("\nPress 1 to register!!!\n");
    printf("Press 2 to download the transaction history file!!!\n");
    printf("Press 3 to check the balance!!!\n");
    printf("Press /q to logout\n");
    bzero( buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    gets(buffer);
    send(sockfd,buffer,BUFSIZE,0);

}

}while (strcmp(buffer,"/q"));
close(sockfd);
}

void catchin(int signo)
{
    printf("\n[ Interrupt signal has been ignored.]\n");
}
```

Comment: To start with, 1. handle errors (e.g `fopen()` may fail. 2. Check your buffer sizes - buffer with 30 bytes may not be sufficient. 3. Use some debugger.

Comment: Use a debugger. And you havevn't even made it clear whether it is the client or the server that seg faults.

Comment: what is your mean that check the buffer sizes???sorry i cant understand, i have ask my lecture also he say same thing to me but he dont want to tell me the solution, can u explain to me a lit bit??

Comment: sorry, its happen when i run the server.c

Comment: i cant even run the server.c , its happen at waiting to bind.... then the program force to terminate

Comment: "i can't even run"..err, your program can't seg fault unless it is running. And don't ignore the best programming advice you'll get for a long time - use a debugger.

Comment: sorry my english is not good, i mean it will stuck at thr and show segmentation fault

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts. 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line, not some random number of blank lines.

Comment: the header file: `inet.h` is missing the 'include guards' `#ifndef INET_H  #define INET_H ....  #endif // INET_H`   The include guards should be in every header file you write.

Comment: the function: `gets()` is depreciated and easily will overrun the input buffer. (and not even in the latest C standard)  suggest using `fgets()`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  the `server` code produces a long set of warnings, all of which need to be fixed.

(for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: the last argument of the `accept()` statement is not correct due to expecting 'unsigned' and passed argument is 'signed'.   The syntax of the call to 'fread()' is `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);` but the posted code has the return type as `int`.  Similar considerations exist for the 3 parameter to `send()`.   There is the unused variable: `bytereceive`.  These problems need to be fixed, before even trying to run the code to debug the logic

Answer (score 0):

Buffer overrun can be the primary cause of segmentation fault here. Program can crash when trying to write to a memory which is out of the allocated limit (30 bytes).

```
char filename[30];
    strcpy(filename, "/home/"); 
    strcat(filename, buf); 
    strcat(filename, "/client/");
    strcat(filename, buffer);
```

There is no guarantee that filename endup within the limit of 30 characters. Instead of using strcat, use snprintf giving the maximum limit of file name length like this:

```
snprintf(filename, 30, "/home/%s/client/%s", buf, buffer);
```

However note that this will truncate the filename if it exceeds 30. So increase the size to a reasonable value.